# regex for several domains

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression to determine when to fire a tracking tag or not.

If a visitor to one of the sites is on one of these three domains the tag should fire:

```
 - www.grousemountainlodge.com 
 - www.glacierparkinc.com
 - reserveglacierdenali.com
```

I actually have a regular expression that works. But I'm not confident and wanted to bounce it off the folk on this board.

This is what I have. Is there a simpler, more elegant or more robust regex to use for matching the 3 domains?

```
^(www\.)?((glacierparkinc|grousemountainlodge)\.com)$|(^reserveglacierdenali\.com)$
```

Following some answers, this regex should exlude other domains e.g. `cats.glacierparkinc.com` or similar.

Comment: Simpler and more elegant? Yes, a list and fixed string searchs :P Unless you need to make partial matchs. Don't overuse regexes unless you **need** them.

Comment: are you matching against the domain names or the a full URL? I guess domains but would be nice if you clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `glacierparkinc.com` should match, without the `www.` prefix - from your list it seems that no, but from your regex it seems it will be matched.

In either case I guess you can simplify it a bit:

```
^(?:www\.(?:glacierparkinc|grousemountainlodge)|reserveglacierdenali)\.com$
```

Note the use of `(?:)` instead of just `()`: this means positive look-ahead assertion without capturing. Its a best practice not to capture when you don't need to - saving time and memory.

Answer (score 1):

It must be at starting position *with* or *not* `www.`. So:

```
^(?:www\.)?(?:glacierparkinc|grousemountainlodge|reserveglacierdenali)\.
```

If it maches, then do something.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dE2mS2/2)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. There sill be several cases where there are subdomains e.g. cats. glacierparkinc.com and those should be excluded

Comment: Thanks again, went with shevron's answer but both worked. I was unaware of positive outlook without capturing